# Pass values from two Barcode Scanners to two specific texboxes.

Tags: vb.net, winforms, barcode-scanner

I have two textboxes in a windowsform `textbox1` and `textbox2`, I am trying to use two barcode scanners to send the values to each textbox.
If i Scan anything from **Barcode Scanner 1** it should send value to `textbox 1` ***without clicking on it!***.

If i Scan anything from **Barcode Scanner 2** it should send value to `textbox 2` ***without clicking on it!***.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A number of barcode readers allow to configure a prefix or suffix (or both) symbols to be sent along with the code. If those you own support this, you can configure a different attachment to identify the "right one ".

Answer (score 1):

Barcode scanners that are USB utilize HID or Human Interface Device.  Typically, these are devices that humans use to directly control the operation of computer systems.

Microsoft offers a complete break down in this technology, I wish I could up load the PDF.  I hate posting url's, as they can become stale; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/introduction-to-hid-concepts

There are a few API's you can research and can be found above, I would investigate these:

Device Discovery and Setup
The following list identifies the HID API that an application can use to: identify the properties of a HID device, and to establish communication with that device. In addition, an application can use some of these API to identify a Top Level Collection.

HidD_GetAttributes

HidD_GetHidGuid

HidD_GetIndexedString

HidD_GetManufacturerString

HidD_GetPhysicalDescriptor

HidD_GetPreparsedData

HidD_GetProductString

HidD_GetSerialNumberString

HidD_GetNumInputBuffers

HidD_SetNumInputBuffers

Data Movement
The following list identifies the HID API that an application can use to move data back and forth between the app and a selected device.

HidD_GetInputReport

HidD_SetFeature

HidD_SetOutputReport

ReadFile

WriteFile

Another approach would be to see if the barcode scanner could emulate a serial port. This would denote which scanner is which, via the comm port.

Answer (score 0):

For such use, there is POS for.NET or OPOS.
Both are part of UnifiedPOS.
[Document -- retail/17-07-32 (UnifiedPOS Retail Peripheral Architecture, Version 1.14.1)](https://www.omg.org/cgi-bin/doc?retail/17-07-32.pdf)

There is information and download here.
[POS for .NET v1.14.1 SDK Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/bb429024(v=winembedded.4))
[Download Microsoft Point of Service for .NET v1.14.1 (POS for.NET)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55758)

[OPOS](http://monroecs.com/opos.htm)
[CCO Current Version](http://monroecs.com/oposccos_current.htm)

Since the program that actually controls the scanner is provided by the scanner vendor, you will obtain it.

Using them you need to create control objects for each individual scanner.

Which object is responsible for which scanner is specified by the DeviceName parameter of the Open method. The DeviceName is associated with USB VID/PID or connected COM port by configuration file or registry data.

Barcodes can be read from the scanner by processing Open, Claim, DeviceEnabled=true, DataEventEnabled=true on that object.

The object is notified by the DataEvent that the barcode has been read.

An application can register a separate event handler for each object, or by registering the same event handler and determining the sender parameter of the event notification, it is possible to identify from which scanner the barcode was read .

An application can read barcode data from the properties of the corresponding object and write it in the corresponding TextBox.